# Recovering forgotten password on ArcMap toolbox (.tbx)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I made an ArcGIS toolbox (.tbx) using ModelBuilder on ArcGIS 10.2 last year and I have to edit something on that tool but I forget the password of that tool.

How can I recover or do anything to edit that tool?

Comment: This sounds like a task for Esri Tech Support; if anyone can help, it will be them

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that you can.

I think you should have put your password on a copy of the toolbox, and kept your source toolbox with no password ready for when you needed to edit it.